# Checking empty fields in android application

Tags: java, android, validation

I Have a form with 3 activities in my application. The user shouldn't go into the 2nd activity if he didn't complete filling-in the fields in 1st activity, the NextButton is kept disabled until the fields are complete.

The form contains: picture, edit text and a spinner..

**Questions:**

1-I created a function that checks whether the spinner and edittext has a value or not... 
but I didn't know where I should call this function...

2- How can I check if the imageview has contains a picture or not?
note: the user will take the picture from the Gallery ..

-----------My Code ------------

```
// For Disabling The Buttons
    void updateButtonState() {


        if(checkimg()&& CheckSpinner() && checkEditText2(CaseName) && checkEditText2(CaseAge) && CheckRButtons(RBMale, RBFemale) ) {
        Nextb.setEnabled(true);}
        else {Nextb.setEnabled(false);}

            }

// For Spinner
    private boolean CheckSpinner(){
        boolean checkspiner=false;
        if( strH == "0" && strM == "0")
            checkspiner=false;
        else checkspiner= true;
        return checkspiner;
    }



// For Buttons

     private boolean CheckRButtons(RadioButton rBMale2, RadioButton rBFemale2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     boolean but = false;
        if ( RBMale.isChecked() || RBFemale.isChecked())
            but = true;
        return but;

}


// For EditText  
         private boolean checkEditText2(EditText edit) {
                return edit.getText().length() != 0;
            }
```

Comment: it's pretty simple , in the onClick() method of your button Next, you check if the text is not null , and the spinner have a selected value, and the image ( getBitmapImage() ) of your ImageView is not null , if those conditions are true , so you will redirect the user to the second activity , and if not , you will display a Toast to tell the user that is something missing on fields :)

Comment: You should follow java naming conventions, your code is hard to read : http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: @Houcine thanks for your answer, but I couldn't use imageView.getBitmapImage(); ??? can you tell me how can  I use it ?!!

Comment: now i'm at work , if you want ,upload your project , and give me the link , i can see it and fix the problem when i will be at home.

Comment: @Samiah : about the checking the ImageView, when you set the bitmap to your imageView , try to set a Tag to your ImageView ( imgView.setTag(myBitmap);
and when you will try to check if there is an image or not , you will just get the tag and test if it's not null ( Bitmap b = (Bitmap) imgView.getTag(); if(b == null ) { //the imageView is empty} else {// there is an image }

Comment: @Houcine thanks alot, it works now .. but I've another problem, ill be appreciated if you take a look at it thanks, here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9785024/about-chatting-application-android

Comment: this is a closed application , you are asking about an app of chat with sms, visit my profile stackoverflow, you will find my email address , and send me what you want , i can't answer the question , it's closed :).
another thing , i will post my comment as an Answer and accept it in order to others can get help from it when they have the same problem of cheking empty fields :)

Comment: @Houcine sorry couldn't find ur email address

Comment: @Samiah : you have it now , you didn't send me anything until now , please tell me if you have note it , i will delete the comment that conatains my address email :)

Comment: @Houcine thanks alot, I've been sent it to u and I'm waiting ur reply thanks in adavance, you can delete it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

about the checking the `ImageView`, when you set the bitmap to your `imageView` , try to set a `Tag` to your `ImageView` like this  :

`imgView.setTag(myBitmap);`

and when you will try to check if there is an image or not , you will just get the tag and test if it's not null :

```
Bitmap b = (Bitmap) imgView.getTag();
if(b == null ) { 
    //the imageView is empty
} 
else {
     // there is an image
}
```